# Почему приложение вылетает

Tags: java, android

[image][image]Подскажите почему мое приложение не работает.Сам пытался  разобраться к сожалению не смог.
Майн акстивити.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<ModelClass> model = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setData();
    RecyclerView recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    // создаем адаптер
    Adapter_class adapter = new Adapter_class(this, model);
    // устанавливаем для списка адаптер
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setData(){

    model.add(new ModelClass (R.color.colorAccent));
    model.add(new ModelClass (R.color.colorAccent));
    model.add(new ModelClass (R.color.colorAccent));
    model.add(new ModelClass (R.color.colorAccent));
}
public void Intent_1(int ButtonPosition){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,for_trenirovryClick.class);
   intent.putExtra("OnClickRecyclerView",ButtonPosition);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

```
public class Adapter_class extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_class.ViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<ModelClass> modelClass;
Context context1;
MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
int positionIndex;

Adapter_class(Context context, List<ModelClass> modelClass) {
    this.modelClass = modelClass;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context1=context;
}
@Override
public Adapter_class.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_class.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ModelClass model_class = modelClass.get(position);
    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(model_class.getBackground());

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           switch (position){
               case 0:mainActivity.Intent_1(0);
               case 2:mainActivity.Intent_1(1);
               case 3:mainActivity.Intent_1(2);
               case 1:mainActivity.Intent_1(3);
           }

        }
    });




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClass.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final Button button;
    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        button =  (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    }

}
```

}

```
public class ModelClass {
private int image;

public ModelClass(int image){ this.image = image;}

public int getBackground() {return this.image; }
```

}

```
public class for_trenirovryClick extends AppCompatActivity {
List<ModelClass2> model = new ArrayList<>();

RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_trenirovry_click);
    Intent intent1=getIntent();
    int i= intent1.getIntExtra("OnClickRecyclerView",1);
    setData();
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);


    // создаем адаптер
    Adapter_class2 adapter = new Adapter_class2(this, model);
    // устанавливаем для списка адаптер
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private void setData(){

    model.add(new ModelClass2 (R.color.colorAccent,"приседания","x 16"));
    model.add(new ModelClass2(R.color.colorAccent,"jkhjjhgjhhjhjgjkhkjkkjkj","x 21"));
    model.add(new ModelClass2 (R.color.colorAccent,"jdjkgjkdfjgkfdfkhdk","x 10"));
    model.add(new ModelClass2 (R.color.colorAccent,"kjhjklkijdhkhdfdsaaa","x 9"));
}
```

}

```
public class ModelClass2 {


private int image_resourse;
private String text_for_ex;
private String text_for_times;



public ModelClass2(int image_resourse, String text_for_ex, String text_for_times) {
    this.image_resourse = image_resourse;
    this.text_for_ex = text_for_ex;
    this.text_for_times = text_for_times;
}


public int getImage_resourse() {
    return this.image_resourse;
}

public String getText_for_ex() {
    return this.text_for_ex;
}

public String getText_for_times() {
    return this.text_for_times;
}
```

}

```
public  class Adapter_class2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_class2.ViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater1;
private List<ModelClass2> modelClass2;


Adapter_class2(Context context, List<ModelClass2> modelClass) {
    this.modelClass2 = modelClass;
    this.inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}
@Override
public Adapter_class2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.item_layout2, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter_class2.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ModelClass2 model_class = modelClass2.get(i);
    viewHolder.imageView_ex.setImageResource(model_class.getImage_resourse());
  viewHolder.kol_times.setText(model_class.getText_for_times());
  viewHolder.name_exercise.setText(model_class.getText_for_ex());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClass2.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final TextView name_exercise;
    final TextView kol_times;
    final ImageView imageView_ex;
    final CheckBox checkBox;
    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name_exercise=view.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        kol_times=view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        imageView_ex=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        checkBox =view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);

    }

}
```

}

При клике на кнопку у меня приложение вылетает[image]

Comment: вы бы хоть стректрейс исключения приложили.

Comment: @pavel что такое стрейклист

Comment: Де логи ???????

Comment: @pavlofff сейчас отправлю

Comment: @pavel отправил

Comment: `MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();` так не делают

Comment: @Jarvis_J чем можно это заменить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаёте вручную экземпляр активити и вызываете на нём методы. Это не будет работать, т.к. все работоспособные экземпляры активити создаются системой.

У вас в коде много проблем, в т.ч. неправильное именование переменных, классов, методов, засим не буду описывать сложное и правильное решение, а покажу простое решение:

Измените ваш адаптер так, чтобы он принимал созданный системой экземпляр активити:

```
public class Adapter_class extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_class.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ModelClass> modelClass;
    Context context1;
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    int positionIndex;

    Adapter_class(MainActivity context, List<ModelClass> modelClass) {
        this.modelClass = modelClass;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context1=context;
        this.mainActivity = context;
    }
```

тут изменена одна строка и одна строка добавлена. После этого ваш код должен заработать.

Comment: Благодарю благодарю